# how to order dates from most recent to least recent

Tags: python, datetime, tkinter, operating-system

So here is this the code I use to insert into the tkinter listbox of downloaded files from the downloads folder to list all .zip files. How would I be able to make sure it orders the files from most recent to least recent?

```
for line in downloads:
            unixtime = os.stat(line).st_mtime
            kws = datetime.fromtimestamp(unixtime)
            if ".zip" in line:
                list.insert(tk.END, str(line), "Date modified: ", kws.date(), "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html): e.g.

```py
from pathlib import Path

src = Path('/your_downloads_directory')

zipfiles_sorted = sorted(src.glob('*.zip'), key=lambda p: p.lstat().st_mtime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the `downloads` list first based on the modification time in reverse order:

```py
downloads = sorted(((os.stat(line).st_mtime, line) for line in downloads if line.endswith('.zip')), reverse=1)
for unixtime, line in downloads:
    kws = datetime.fromtimestamp(unixtime)
    listbox.insert(tk.END, line, 'Date modified:', kws.date())
```